# Why is this NSLocalizedString not being Reverse for Hebrew

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I have the following statement :

```
NSString* mess = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"this_statement", nil),
                            value,
                            friendName];
```

the localized statement in Hebrew is :

```
    "this_statement" = "אמריקה <b>%@</b> אל %@‎‏.";
```

In English :

```
    "this_statement" = "America <b>%@</b> to %@.";
```

Now, when i actually do instantiate `mess` and run it, the value returned is printed and reversed, but the stuff I passed i.e. `value` and `friendName` are not reversed as Hebrew should be. Can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

NSLocalizedString is executed first an so "this_statement" is looked up first and then the result has the *value* and *friendName* inserted into it. If you want localisation for 'value' and 'friendName' to occur you will have to wrap them in NSLocalizedString also. For example

```
NSString* mess = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"this_statement", nil),
                            NSLocalizedString(value, nil),
                            NSLocalizedString(friendName, nil)];
```

You will have to supply localised values for what every *value* and *friendName* can be.